# Branch Deep link not opening application

Tags: ios, applinks, branch.io

I have been trying (unsuccessfully) to use [Branch](https://dev.branch.io/) to implement deep linking into our iOS application. The Branch URL redirects directly to App Store and never attempts to open the application. I must be missing something.

What I've done:

1. Included Branch SDK (CocoaPods) Added `branch_key` to application
   plist
2. Added URL Scheme to URL Types in application plist
3. Enabled`Associated Domains` in both the project and the App ID in
   the developer console.
4. Ensured that the entitlements file is included in the build.
5. Registered deep link handler in AppDelegate

Dashboard: Settings -> Link Settings:

1. "Always try to open app" is checked
2. "IOS URI Scheme" is set to the application's custom URI scheme.
3. "Enable Universal Links" is checked.
4. Bundle Identifier & Apple App Prefix are both set correctly.

   Within the Branch Dashboard, under "Marketing" tab, I've created a single link. I'm emailing this link to myself and opening it on the device (Mail.app). Safari opens then the App Store is opened as if the application is not installed.

Neither `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation` nor `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler` are called.

AppDelegate Methods:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let branch: Branch = Branch.getInstance()
    branch.initSessionWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, andRegisterDeepLinkHandler: { params, error in
        if (error == nil) {
            // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
            // params will be empty if no data found
            // ... insert custom logic here ...
            NSLog("params: %@", params.description)
        }
    })
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    // pass the url to the handle deep link call
    
    return Branch.getInstance().continueUserActivity(userActivity)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    // pass the url to the handle deep link call
    Branch.getInstance().handleDeepLink(url);
    
    // do other deep link routing for the Facebook SDK, Pinterest SDK, etc
    return true
}
```

Am I missing a configuration step? Is this because the application is installed via Xcode debug and not through the app store? I'm expecting to see the application delegate methods called, but they are not.

Comment: i m facing BAD EXCESS in the line of 
        let branch: Branch = Branch.getInstance() in app delegate class, can u give suggestion for this, im also using swift

Comment: @Nick : Have you found the solution.?

Answer (score 14):

It appears that the application must be installed via App Store/Test Flight/Ad Hoc or the application will not be considered installed.

I installed the application to my device using an Ad Hoc provision and everything is working.

Comment: I'm having this same issue at the moment. They were working fine about 2.5 months ago and now I'm getting sent to Safari immediately. What do you mean by ad hoc install? They won't work if you're running the device off Xcode?

Comment: @spacemonkey I found that I could not test the deep linking running the application in Debug mode with XCode. The application needed to be installed to the device via Ad Hoc deployment or by the App Store. My assumption is that iOS is not reporting the application "installed" when deployed via XCode Debug. Learn about Ad Hoc Distribution here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

Comment: Thank for the help. And I can confirm that. I did a distribution with Fabric to debug deep links and everything works fine on devices that have been installed that way.

Comment: @Nick : My dynamic and market links were working fine almost a month back but since yesterday these links re-direct me to safari and then to app store instead of the app. I have checked all setting thrice and also on after I move from safari to my app then I get callback on branch io method with params.

Comment: Does it also work for In House Deployment ? I tried with In House deployment, with branch configured to open a custom HTML file if the App is not installed, but till now the link is not opening my app (on Debug and In House modes)

Comment: Alex from Branch.io: this is ***NOT*** accurate. Branch links work correctly when the app is installed via Xcode — this is certainly due to some other configuration issue.

Comment: @AlexBauer So, my test users on Enterprise development account cannot test out Universal Links, can they?

Comment: @AdityaSaxena they should be able to. Universal Links have no connection to the how the app is initially installed on the device. Branch should also work fine, with the possible exception of when the app is not installed prior to link click

Comment: @AlexBauer What is happening with me is when I try to run the app via cordova command line onto my device, the deeplink xxxx.app.link doesn't work. But, when I run the same code via XCode(without changing any setting), the same xxxx.app.link starts working. That leads me to believe that there must be some configuration that XCode applies by itself (please note my teamid and bundleid are all fine as I dont change those when running via Xcode)

Comment: @AdityaSaxena that's odd! Would you mind submitting a ticket to our [Integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) so we can investigate this?

Comment: @AlexBauer Thanks. Will do

Comment: When I try to run App on my iPhone connected to XCode, deeplinking works fine, but when I make a build (Archive and export) and upload it on Diawi. In the app installed from Diawi, the deeplinking stops working. I am not sure why this is happening. Will the build work when installed from testFlight?

Answer (score 12):

For me, the link worked even though I installed tethered without Adhoc distribution. Then one day it stopped working. That was because I clicked on the forward link to bnc inside the app.

The fix for that was easy - just long pressed the link. An option shows "Open in App". Click this and the link is handled by app. Next time onwards, link works as expected even without long press as Safari remembers this as the default behavior.

Comment: @kdeo, did u integrated with Swift, if so, i need some help, i tried with this in swift but, following method not executing inside.    let branch: Branch = Branch.getInstance()
    branch.initSessionWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, andRegisterDeepLinkHandler: { params, error in
        if (error == nil) {
            // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
            NSLog("params: %@", params.description)
        }
    })

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue - some of the answers here are dated so I'll try to provide an update:

> The fix for that was easy - just long pressed the link. An option shows "Open in App".

This went away in iOS 11 I believe so unless you're testing in iOS 10 this isn't an option.

> It appears that the application must be installed via App Store/Test Flight/Ad Hoc or the application will not be considered installed.

As Alex pointed out in the comments this is not accurate. Branch links work when the app is installed via Xcode.

For me the issue was some sort of caching problem on my device. I have multiple schemes Debug & Release each of which has their own branch key and links. Some how they got mixed up and links wouldn't open in one scheme. I was able to resolve this issue by force restarting the device.

Comment: That was exactly my problem. Restarting device and reinstalling the app from Xcode solved the issue! Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

I also had same issue, but mine solution is different than yours.

*Note:* We can open the App in debug mode, (I did it, as pointed out by [Alex Bauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5394680/alex-bauer)  in above comment section).

In `.plist` I added two different keys one is `live` and another one is `test` (simultaneously), along with above mentioned configuration settings.

The domain for deep linking which I was using was this. `bnc.lt`.
I mailed to Branch Io support team regarding my issue, then got reply as follows'

> The reason you are having issues is because you are still on our legacy `bnc.lt` link domain. This link domain has been slowly phased out over the past year. Development and functionality have stopped for quite some time in favor of our new link domain (app.link). 
>   To fix your issues and get your AASA validator working correctly, you will need to change your link domain from bnc.lt to app.link on your Branch Dashboard (https://dashboard.branch.io/settings/link). Once you have made this change, you will need to update your app to accept the new app.link link domain as well as your old bnc.lt link domain. https://gist.github.com/ethanneff/a2a70d1b3518c638701c28b1bd374e80

Please visit the above link its very helpful.

Hope it solves your issue, Happy Branching :)