# Branch io iOS links always redirect to App Store instead of our app

Tags: ios, xcode, branch.io

I was able to get the Marketing links working once, but the Smart Banner never worked. The Marketing links would open in our app.

Then this broke when I tapped the Smart Banner link and installed the (live) app from the App Store.

Even after deleting both apps, reinstalling the test app from Xcode, Marketing links will no longer work, redirection always happens to the App Store even if the app is installed.

The test app has the same bundle identifier as the live app so integration should be (and was) working.

More details:

- Clicking on a Marketing link or banner opens up the App Store (via Safari) every time
- Then I go to my app manually and if I scroll, thus refreshing the output on Xcode debug panel, I can see the link details coming from Branch.
- Seems the link is making it to the app but in a deferred manner, after the redirection to the App Store is happening.
- And our app is not being recognised as it is never opened from either a link in Notes or the banner from Safari on the iPhone.
- Universal linking is enabled.
- We are using iOS 9.3 and Xcode 7.3.1
- Our app has been set up with the proper `branch.io` settings, key, schemes and URLs.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you create URL schemes?

Comment: @Kakubei : I am facing the same problem with branch.io. Any solution found ..? follow my question here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930717/branch-io-redirects-to-app-store-only-though-app-is-already-present-in-device/39933801#39933801

Comment: @Kakubei : Did you found any solution..?

Comment: Please go through my solution for same problem as yours [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138257/branch-deep-link-not-opening-application/42690708#42690708)

Comment: Please go through my solution for the same problem as yours.[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138257/branch-deep-link-not-opening-application/42690708#42690708)

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you by any chance tap the "bnc.lt" link at the status bar of your iPhone while the app is running. Once you do that, the links will always redirect to AppStore. Try long-tapping the deep link, and in the menu that pops up choose "Open in [your app]".

Comment: Thanks, I read that but this is not the case. Long-pressing doesn't give me the option to open in app.

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: this is usually a good place to start for symptoms like these.

Comment: First time, it didn't give me option but by tapping second or third time, i get that option.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with Branch.io I realized that branch.io links will redirect to your app only once. I think its a feature provided by branch.io. To test again you need regenerate new links.

Comment: This is not so. When everything was working, the links would redirect each time.

Comment: check this [link](https://support.branch.io/support/solutions/articles/6000039872-why-does-my-link-always-redirect-to-the-app-store-play-store-)

Comment: Thanks @hammad, I do have the option to `Always try to open the app` turned on.

Comment: Are you using sandbox mode? We have noticed that in the recent few months, the links in Production mode behave OK, but the links in sandbox mode behave in the way that you have described.

Comment: For Live Mode it works fine for me, but for Test Mode it behaves in the way that you have described. I would also like to have the Test Mode behave correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here: could you [submit a ticket](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) to our Integration Engineering team for this issue? It looks like we may need to do some debugging on the backend of your app config.