# Branch.io redirects to app store only though app is already present in device

Tags: ios, iphone, branch.io

In my one of the apps I have implemented branch.io.

I have read each and everything and settled my account accordingly.

> Now what I want from branch.io
>
> 1) If app is present in device it should open on the click of
>   marketing url.
>
> 2) If app is not present in device then it should redirect to app
>   store application page.**
>
> **What is not working**
>
> 1> Though app is present but it is not opening my app. From same url
>   schema I can open my app from safari browser "appname://" but not able
>   to open from link of branch.io. It always opens app store page.

Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Alex from Branch.io here. What you want from Branch is exactly what we do, so let's figure out what is going wrong!

This sounds like a Universal Links configuration issue. If you did not get Universal Links set up fully, then Branch links *will* redirect to the App Store. If you haven't yet set up Universal Links, go ahead and complete [this guide](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/) to get started. If you **have** set up Universal Links, we have a [troubleshooting guide](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#troubleshooting-universal-links) you can run through to catch most issues.

Comment: Checked everything but didn't found anything. Looks like everything is settled up nicely but still not working. I am not sure what to do at this moment.

Comment: If you've been through all the troubleshooting steps and are stilling having difficulty, I recommend submitting a ticket with the Branch [integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new). They can help dig through your specific code and figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following if you are on iOS:

1. you have multiple bundle ids registered.
2. branch only considers the first bundle-id in the list of configured bundle-ids for universal links.