# Branch.io Deep link not opening application in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking, branch.io, applinks

I am using [Brach SDK](https://dev.branch.io/) to implement deep linking into our iOS Application. The Branch URL redirects directly to App Store if I am opening from FB, Skype, LinkedIn iOS App. But it redirecting to our app if we are opening from the Whatsapp and Twitter.

I have followed all the steps which is written into [this doc](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking#generate-tracked-deep-linking-urls-pass-data-across-install-and-open) and [this que](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35138257/3908884). I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35140336/3908884), the app will be open if it is installed from the App Store/Test Flight/Ad Hoc. I have tried this, but not able to get success into this.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *restorableObjects))restorationHandler
{
    BOOL handledByBranch = [[Branch getInstance] continueUserActivity:userActivity];

    return handledByBranch;
}
```

Let me know, I have missed anything to implement this. The Branch URL redirects directly to App Store if I am opening from FB, Skype, LinkedIn iOS App. **So How can I open app from this apps via Branch URL..?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to check it with the Brach SDK, maybe they can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Branch.io here: Facebook, Skype, and LinkedIn all do not support Universal Links on iOS. This means it is not possible to launch your app directly from the feed in any of these apps.

You'll need to enable the [Deepviews](https://dev.branch.io/features/deepviews/overview/) feature. This will open a preview of your content in a web view, with a button that your user can click to open the app. It's an extra step, but currently the best option available.